# How does JavaScript handle garbage in modern browsers such as Chrome?

Tags: javascript

Suppose `getLargeArray()` returns a very large array of many items. I declared a variable called "items" and initialize it with a very large array. Then, I reassign a small array to the variable, `items`, like the following:

```
var items = getLargeArray();

items = ["dog","cat","pig"];
```

What will happen to the memory that stores the large array? Does `items` points to the memory that holds the data? Or, is it a pointer to the address that holds the first element of the array? If I keep doing that, what will happen to my application on Chrome?

Comment: **big** topic.  Where to begin...  maybe read the v8 blog about the garbage collector [here](https://v8.dev/blog/trash-talk)?

Comment: Short answer: if an object (such as your array) is no longer reachable, it is eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: `items` is a _reference_ to the array, not a pointer to the first element.

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+garbage+collection) of [What is JavaScript garbage collection?](/q/864516/4642212) and [When and How JavaScript garbage collector works](/q/58100536/4642212). Have you read these? Did these not answer all your questions?

Comment: @SebastianSimon These posts don't explain how garbage collection work on modern browsers specifically.